# How can I move files based on their name?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move files into existing sub-folders based on the file names.

For example, I want to move a file named `AP16742` found in the directory `X:\Files` into a folder named `AP` in the directory `X:\Files\AP`. Other files named `MO14823` I want to move into a folder named `MO` in the directory `X:\Files\MO`.

I'm inexperienced in coding, so I need explanations to go with a provided example.

This is what I tried:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir" 
SET "destdir=U:\destdir" 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%*.xml" ') DO ( 
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO ( 
    FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ( 'dir /b /ad "%destdir%*%%b*" ' ) DO ( 
      ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\" 
    ) 
  ) 
) 
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you mean move or copy?  There is an actual sort command in Windows but that physically sorts a file by telling it what position you want to start the sort on.

Comment: I've seen a bunch of similar looking scripts, but not sure where I should edit. I'm very much a novice at coding, seeking to become less ignorant.

Comment: Seeing things like:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xml" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
  ) DO (
   ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF but not sure where to make my changes

Comment: @MSR76 Next time [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50613783/edit) the question yourself to contain code / additional information.

Comment: It would be clearer when your sample code reflected the directory names you mentioned in your description... Anyway, do the files have no file name extension?

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation would have been:

- you want to distribute files in `X:\Files` to subfolders with the
  first 2 letters of the file name.
- To get a substring you need to set the content from for variable into
  a normal variable.
- Setting and using a variable inside a (code block) requires delayed
  expansion.

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Pushd "X:\Files"

For %%A in (*) do (
  Set "File=%%~nA"
  if not exist "!File:~0,2!" md "!File:~0,2!" 2>&1>Nul
  Move "%%A" "!File:~0,2!"
)
Popd
```

In case you want to move only distinct 2 letter pairs and not all files that's also possible without great effort.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of LotPings answer, this uses `RoboCopy` with its `/MOV` option, *which will create directories as needed and move the files to them*:

```bat
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "X:\Files" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In (*) Do (Set "File=%%~nA"
    RoboCopy . "!File:~,2!" "%%A" /MOV >Nul)
```